# OOP programming with data encapsulation in C

Tags: c, oop, pointers, struct, linker

I tried to do data encapsulation in C based on this post here https://alastairs-place.net/blog/2013/06/03/encapsulation-in-c/.

In a header file I have:

```
#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H
#define FUNCTIONS_H

// Pre-declaration of struct. Contains data that is hidden
typedef struct person *Person;


void getName(Person obj);
void getBirthYear(Person obj);
void getAge(Person obj);
void printFields(const Person obj);

#endif
```

In ´functions.c´ I have defined the structure like that

```
#include "Functions.h"

enum { SIZE = 60 };

struct person
{
    char name[SIZE];
    int birthYear;
    int age;
};
```

pluss I have defined functions as well.

In main.c I have:

```
#include "Functions.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    // Works because *Person makes new a pointer
    Person new = malloc(sizeof new);

    getName(new);
    getAge(new);
    getBirthYear(new);
    printFields(new);

    free(new);

    return 0;
}
```

Is it true, that when I use `Person new`, `new` is already pointer because of `typedef struct person *Person;`.

How is it possible, that linker cannot see the body and members that I have declared in my `struct person`

Is this only possible using pointer?

Is the correct (and only) way to implement OOP prinicples in my case to make a different `struct` in `functions.h` like so:

```
typedef struct classPerson
{   // This data should be hidden
    Person data;

    void (*fPtrGetName)(Person obj);
    void (*fPtrBirthYear)(Person obj);
    void (*fPtrGetAge)(Person obj);
    void (*fPtrPrintFields)(const Person obj);
} ClassPerson;
```

Comment: Never `typedef` pointers! It guarantees confusion and inhibits using `const` qualifier on the objects. If that is from the linked site, they are wrong. Just `typedef the `struct`. And that is not OOP, just information hiding.

Comment: @Olaf Information hiding, aka private encapsulation, is one of the necessary corner-stones of OOP. The others being modular design and inheritance. All 3 can be achieved with this method. You need nothing else but those 3 for proper OOP. Everything else you might stumble upon in languages with OO support is just misc fluff of diverse usefulness.

Comment: @Lundin: Not really. The major issue for OOP is objects to provide the functions to manipulate them **with them**. If you still have object and method seperated, there is no OOP. As much as modular programming is not OOP - that is standard in all halfway modern programming languages. I'm not sure if I agree with inheritance being a necessary part of OOP. What about duck-typing? No OOP, just the same interface.

Comment: @Olaf Why would that matter? A re-entrant C function taking a pointer to opaque type is not different from lets say a C++ member function with a `this` pointer in any meaningful way. If it is polymorphism you're fishing for, then function pointers can be used as in this example, they will have to be set from the "constructor". Just as in C++, you can decide if the inherited function will call the base class function or replace it.

Comment: @Lundin: Yes, but the code above is far from that. I don't speculate where it **might** go. And the C++ way is not the only OOP way. I'm not even sure it should be used in a C-style OOP implementation (too much casting, too complicated to handle or too fancy macro-magic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it is usually better to not hide pointers behind a typedef, but to let the caller use pointer types. This prevents all kinds of misunderstandings when reading and maintaining the code. For example `void printFields(const Person obj);` looks like nonsense if you don't realize that `Person` is a pointer type.

> Have I understood correctly, that when I use Person new, new is already pointer because of typedef struct person *Person;.

Yes. You are confused because of the mentioned typedef.

> How is it possible, that linker cannot see the body and members that I have declared in my ´struct person´?

The linker can see everything that is linked, or you wouldn't end up with a working executable.

The *compiler* however, works on "translation units" (roughly means a .c file and all its included headers). When compiling the caller's translation unit, the compiler doesn't see functions.c, it only sees functions.h. And in functions.h, the struct declaration gives an *incomplete type*. Meaning "this struct definition is elsewhere".

> Is this only possible using pointer?

Yes, it is the only way if you want to do proper OO programming in C. This concept is sometimes called *opaque pointers* or *opaque type*.

(Though you could also achieve "poor man's private encapsulation" though the `static` keyword. Which is usually not really recommended, since it wouldn't be thread-safe.)

> Is the correct (and only) way to implement OOP prinicples in my case to make a different struct in functions.h like so:

Pretty much, yeah (apart from the nit-pick about the mentioned pointer typedef). Using function pointers to the public functions isn't necessary though, although that's how you implement polymorphism.

What your example lacks though is a "constructor" and "destructor". Without them the code wouldn't be meaningful. The malloc and free calls should be inside those, and not done by the caller.

Comment: Well, `const Person obj` on a pointer type most likely is not what one wants to have `const` qualified.

Comment: @Olaf Nicely spotted. Indeed, it makes the pointer itself read-only, and not the pointed-at data as was likely intended. So they hid a pointer behind a typedef then only got a few lines before they shot themselves in the foot and wrote a subtle bug.

Comment: Which actually means that you can't achieve const correctness with the pointer-behind-typedef, unless you do something insane like Hungarian notation `typedef const struct person *cPerson; // very bad idea`

Comment: Worse: This is the wrong variant of hungarian notation. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation ). And you'd have to `typedef` two names for each object, flooding global namespace. (It becomes worse if you also need some objects `volatile` qualified). That's why I strictly never accept `typedef`ed pointers.

Comment: @Olaf Agree with `typedef` ing "normal" pointers is nonsense. Disagree for function pointers.

Comment: @tofro: Yes, I forgot about them. For complex functions, a `typedef` can enhance readability. But that exception can easily be justified: functions are no objects, so you cannot declare function objects anyway, but only pointers. So the `typedef` is unambigous (any you cannot qualify functions).

Comment: @tofro If you do `typedef void func_t (void)` then function pointers turn consistent with normal pointers: `func_t* ptr;`. I prefer that style.

Comment: @Lundin - So I have to change the `typedef` version to `struct person *obj`, and change all function arguments then to `struct person *obj`? And then do the allocation as `struct person *new = malloc(sizeof(new)); ` ? And because my `struct` is defined in `functions.c` I can't know the `size` of my `struct` therefore I can't use `sizeof *new` inside `malloc`, I have to remove the `*`. And when I pass `new` to the function's argument in `main`, then inside the function it points to the address of the `struct`. Is it so or I have misunderstood something?

Comment: If you want to keep the structure completely opaque, the "constructor" function should go in the implementation file of the object as some sort of `personNew` function rather than creating the structure in your `main` function - because that is the only place that should need to know the size of the Person object.

Comment: @Lundin - That is definitively a matter of taste - I don't like to `typedef` something I cannot use - I rather typedef as a pointer and make it clear through the name that this is a function pointer (`creationFuncPtr`) or somesuch). FPtrs are so rarely used that I like to see that...

Comment: @Lauri Yes you can change the arguments to that, or just to `person* obj`. The `malloc` needs to be inside the "constructor" inside functions.c. There it knows the size of the struct.

Comment: @Lauri Please note that without a constructor, there is also no way for you to initialize the struct.

Comment: @tofro - How about the other functions? Can I do as I have written with the other ones?

Comment: @Lundin - I see. However, what I have in main now somehow works too. `struct person *new = malloc(sizeof(new));` For at least creating one `struct`.

Comment: @Lundin - And it shows `Functions.h:7:14: error: unknown type name 'person'` if I leave `struct` out and use only `person *obj` as arguments.

Comment: @Lauri You'll have to do `typedef struct person person;`.

Answer (score 0):

With or without typedef, in C you hide data by declaring incomplete types.  In `/usr/include/stdio.h`, you'll find **fread**(3) takes a `FILE *` argument:

```
extern size_t fread (void *__restrict __ptr, size_t __size,
                     size_t __n, FILE *__restrict __stream) __wur;
```

and `FILE` is declared something like this:

```
struct _IO_FILE;
typedef struct _IO_FILE FILE;
```

Using `stdio.h` you cannot define a variable of type `FILE`, because type `FILE` is incomplete: it's declared, but not defined.  But you can happily pass `FILE *` around, because all data pointers are the same size.  You're just going to have to call **fopen**(3) to make it point to an open file.

To *partially* define a type, as in your case:

```
struct classPerson
{   // This data should be hidden
    Person data;

    void (*fPtrGetName)(Person obj);
...
};
```

is a little trickier.  First of all, you should have a really good reason, namely that two implementations of `fPtrGetName` are implemented.  Otherwise you're just building complexity on the altar of OOP.

A good example of a good reason is **bind**(2).  You can bind a unix domain socket or a network socket, among others.  Both types are represented by `struct sockaddr`, but that's just a stand-in type for `struct sockaddr_un` and `struct sockaddr_in`.  Functions that take `struct sockaddr` depend on the fact that all such structures start with the member `sun_family`, and branch accordingly.  *Et voila*, polymorphism: one function, many types.

For an example of a struct full of function pointers, I recommend looking at [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/mem_methods.html).  Its API is loaded with structures to isolate it from the OS and let the user define plug-ins.

BTW, if I may say so, `fPtrGetName` is a terrible name.  It's not interesting that it's a function pointer and (controversy!) "get" is noise on a function that takes no arguments.  Compare

```
struct classPerson sargent;
sargent.fPtrGetName();
sargent.name();
```

Which would you rather use?  I reserve "get" (or similar) for I/O functions; at least then you're getting something, not just moving it from one pocket to another!  For setting, in C++ I overload the function, so that get/set functions have the same name, but in C I wind up with e.g. `set_name(const char name[])`.